# Repository of old versions of windows binary library wheels for Python?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, installation-package

As a lot of users, I use the great [Christopher's Windows binaries wheels](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#vlfd) when trying to install some python packages on Windows (such as GDAL or Fiona). However, now I need a version GDAL 2.1.4 which is one step older than the one available at the site (2.2.2). Anybody would know if there is a repository of old wheels? Thanks.

Comment: Either that or wheel 2.2.2 is not fully functional!

Comment: Hmm. Now I need numpy+mkl version 1.11 but only 1.13 is available...