# One more GDAL import error in Windows

Tags: python, windows, numpy, importerror, gdal

I have installed (and uninstalled) and installed `GDAL 2.2.2` in `Windows 10` using Christoph wheel. However, when I try to import it I get:

```
Installing collected packages: GDAL
Successfully installed GDAL-2.2.2
(e4) C:\Users\R1702898\Documents\Empirical_v4>python
Python 3.4.4 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Jun 15 2016, 15:25:08)     
[MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from osgeo import ogr
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Users\R1702898\Documents\e4\lib\site-packages\osgeo\__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
_gdal = swig_import_helper()
File "C:\Users\R1702898\Documents\e4\lib\site-packages\osgeo\__init__.py", line 31, in swig_import_helper
_mod = imp.load_module('_gdal', fp, pathname, description)
File "C:\Users\R1702898\Documents\e4\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
ImportError: DLL load failed with error code -1073741795
```

The only way it is possible to install in Windows is using the wheels. All else fails. The only available wheel is for `version 2.2.2`
All other dependencies: Fiona, six, numpy, pandas are installed. Although geopandas won't import either (because it needs ogr). I have also set the path to the bin.

Any help. Please. Thanks.

Comment: I personally would use Conda, that solves the large majority of these errors. Because GDAL relies on Numpy, i think they need to be compiled with the same compiler?

Comment: Tried conda conda-force pip everything. I think it is a problem of adjusting paths... I will try uninstalling everything once more!

Comment: It seems that GDAL 2.2.1 is incompatible with a lot of other modules. I reiterate the question: Does anybody know how to obtain an older wheel version? Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46366884/repository-of-old-versions-of-windows-binary-library-wheels-for-python

Comment: I have used GDAL 2.2.1 since it came out till 2.2.2, always builds from conda-forge. I never encounter any issues with them. I'm using Win 10 64bit. You could try using something like Dependency Walker to delve into the error a bit more.

Comment: Is there an order of installing one should follow? How do I prevent my virtual environment from acessing the original Anaconda folder? @rutger-kassies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the things i would avoid is to mix and match different ways of installing. If you are using Conda already, stick to it. I only use pip install as a last resort. Because GDAL uses compiled code, it can get messy if you install packages relying on GDAL which are build with different compilers, something you probably are encountering. That's exactly what Conda solves by carefully looking at requirements and dependencies.

In your case, part of the difficulty comes from using Fiona, although its a great package, they have some very strict version requirements making it not the easiest dependency to have. See the yaml from Conda-Forge:
https://github.com/conda-forge/fiona-feedstock/blob/master/recipe/meta.yaml

On my machine (Win 10 64bit) its still possible to get all packages you list above by only using Conda,

My approach would be:

1) Update your Conda to a recent version (`conda update conda -n root`)

2) Create a new environment:

```
conda create -n gdaltest python=3.6 gdal fiona geopandas numpy -c conda-forge
```

Because of the restrictions in some of the recipes, it solves (for me) to using for example Numpy 1.11, instead of the latest 1.13.

3) Activate the new environment (`activate gdaltest`) and check if the activation script has worked. That should set the environment variables correctly, this is an important step when it comes to conflicts.

In cmd run `SET` and check if `GDAL_DATA` is set to the environment you just activated. Also check if your activate environment comes first in the `PATH` variable, it should have added several folders from your environment (like `..\Library\bin`, `..\Scripts` etc).

That should be sufficient. You can check it by starting Python (make sure the correct environment is active) and start importing gdal, fiona etc.

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a look and try and I'll get back to you.

Comment: Yes. It worked fine. Thanks. Finally, I can tell you... I never knew you could install three libraries at once. Living and learning. Best,

Comment: Excellent, glad it worked out! The benefit of doing all at once is, any dependency issues show immediately before even creating the environment. That way its more easy to for example 'try again' with a different Python version.

Comment: Another exact same problem. I install (using conda-forge) `statsmodels` the prompt says it is installed and then, cannot import: `# All requested packages already installed.
# packages in environment at C:\Anaconda3:
#
statsmodels               0.6.1               np111py34_0    conda-forge

(C:\Anaconda3\envs\e36) >python main.py run
  File "main.py", line 26, in <module>
    import validation
  File "C:\\validation\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from statsmodels.tsa.api import VAR
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'statsmodels'`